# Change the Parent keep the child

Tags: reactjs

*Note: I'm using React Hooks.

I'm trying to make a component that can switch between two functionalities, A/B. Both functionalities has the same child. The struggle that I'm having is when switching between the functionalities, I only see the initial state of the child. Meaning, if I changed anything in the child in functionality A and switched to functionality B then all I see is the initial state of the child. I'm trying to make the child state get updated and appear the same between the two functionalities.

```
           HolderHook
           /        \
           A        B
            \      /
              Child
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
Toggle=>false
HolderHook
    |_ChildRef = useRef(<Child/>) <=== {name: }
    |_Parent A
      |_ ChildRef{name: Potato} <=== after change
```

```
Toggle=>true
HolderHook
    |_ChildRef = useRef(<Child/>) <==={name: potato} <== after Parent A changes
    |_Parent B
      |_ ChildRef{name: Potato} <=== since it is a reference, it should be this.
```

What I'm getting:

```
Toggle=>false
HolderHook
    |_ChildRef = useRef(<Child/>) <=== {name: }
    |_Parent A
      |_ ChildRef{name: Potato} <=== after change
```

```
Toggle=>true
HolderHook
    |_ChildRef = useRef(<Child/>)
    |_Parent B
      |_ ChildRef{name: } <===initial state of Child
```

Comment: is it possible to share some source code?

Comment: Also what do you mean by - Both functionalities has the same child ?

Comment: @Raushan ... the child is just a component that holds values. Like, couple of textboxs

Comment: @Raushan It is like Parent A putting the child in display. Parent B is Editing the child. So, Parent A, doesn't have Buttons to do anything to the child. Parent B, have a Button to send and update the child in some DB.

Comment: How are you actually updating `name`? It seems like you have two instances of `Child`, so updating `name` in Child(A) won't update in Child(B) unless you're storing it in the `state` of a common ancestor.

Comment: @sallf ... I updated the question to accommodate what I described. You are right, I am holding a reference of the child in the HolderHook and passing it to both Parent A and Parent B. Hypothetically, since I'm holding a reference,they both should have the same child. However, They are not.